# "merge" in R replaces real values with NAs

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 tables

- data_id
- data_id1

I need to merge them. Most of the columns are the same, so only info from column called "FLatSchool" will actually be added from data_id1 to data_id:

```
all_data = merge (data_id, data_id_1, by=c("ID_w2", "ID_w3", "ID_w4", "ID_w5",
                                        "ID_MC_w3", "ID_MC_w5",
                                        "School", "Class"),
              all.x = T )
```

Before merging, I check "data_id1" and see that there are different (numeric) values in the column "FLatSchool". However, when both tables are merged this column in the resulting table only contains NAs (there are no problems with other columns, only with this one). What might be the problem?

Data:

```
> dput(data_id)
structure(list(School = c(3L, 3L, 3L), Class = c(10L, 10L, 10L
), ID_w2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("RU8_800", "RU8_801", "RU8_802"
), class = "factor"), ID_all = 71163901:71163903, ID_w3 = 427748:427750, 
ID_MC_w3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("stp94660", "stp94661", 
"stp94662"), class = "factor"), ID_w4 = 428617:428619, ID_w5 = 
428725:428727, 
ID_MC_w5 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("STP114890", "STP114891", 
"STP114892"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("School", "Class", 
"ID_w2", "ID_all", "ID_w3", "ID_MC_w3", "ID_w4", "ID_w5", "ID_MC_w5"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")


> dput(data_id_1)
structure(list(ID_w2 = structure(c(NA, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("RU8_235", 
"RU8_239"), class = "factor"), ID_w3 = 427521:427523, ID_MC_w3 = 
structure(1:3, .Label = c("stp94433", 
"stp94434", "stp94435"), class = "factor"), ID_w4 = 428390:428392, 
ID_w5 = 428781:428783, ID_MC_w5 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("stp114946", 
"stp114947", "stp114948"), class = "factor"), School = c(1L, 
1L, 1L), Class = c(5L, 5L, 5L), FLatSchool = c(1L, 1L, 1L
)), .Names = c("ID_w2", "ID_w3", "ID_MC_w3", "ID_w4", "ID_w5", 
"ID_MC_w5", "School", "Class", "FLatSchool"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I get after using the scrip above is

```
> dput(all_data)
structure(list(ID_w2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("RU8_800", "RU8_801", 
"RU8_802"), class = "factor"), ID_w3 = 427748:427750, ID_w4 = 
428617:428619, 
ID_w5 = 428725:428727, ID_MC_w3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("stp94660", 
"stp94661", "stp94662"), class = "factor"), ID_MC_w5 = structure(1:3, 
.Label = c("STP114890", 
"STP114891", "STP114892"), class = "factor"), School = c(3L, 
3L, 3L), Class = c(10L, 10L, 10L), ID_all = 71163901:71163903, 
FLatSchool = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = 
c("ID_w2", 
"ID_w3", "ID_w4", "ID_w5", "ID_MC_w3", "ID_MC_w5", "School", 
"Class", "ID_all", "FLatSchool"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

What I expect is

```
> dput(all_data)
structure(list(ID_w2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("RU8_800", "RU8_801", 
"RU8_802"), class = "factor"), ID_w3 = 427748:427750, ID_w4 = 
428617:428619, 
ID_w5 = 428725:428727, ID_MC_w3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("stp94660", 
"stp94661", "stp94662"), class = "factor"), ID_MC_w5 = structure(1:3, 
.Label = c("STP114890", 
"STP114891", "STP114892"), class = "factor"), School = c(3L, 
3L, 3L), Class = c(10L, 10L, 10L), ID_all = 71163901:71163903, 
FLatSchool = c(1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("ID_w2", 
"ID_w3", "ID_w4", "ID_w5", "ID_MC_w3", "ID_MC_w5", "School", 
"Class", "ID_all", "FLatSchool"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible data for data_id and data_id1? Also I suspect you may have issues with your 'by' argument but need reproducible data to be able to conclude

Comment: Please add reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know how to give you the data. Should I put them at some hosting and provide a link?

Comment: @AlexM `dput(data)`.

Comment: Done! See above (in the post)

Comment: the `factors` are probably the problem... change them to character before joining...

Comment: The data you provided, does not have rows in common, take for example the column ``ID_w2``: in ``data_id_1`` it has the values ``<NA> ,   RU8_239, RU8_235``, where in ``data_id`` it has ``RU8_800, RU8_801, RU8_802``

Comment: @Wimpel I tried, it doesn't work unfortunately...

Comment: @DS_UNI that's true, cause I only subsetted these lines in order to show the example of data. However, it shouldn't influence the result, because I set all.x = T in the command. I should just get NA in lines that don't correspond each other, but (!) not in the whole column "FLatSchool" as soon as there are some values there initially

Comment: @AlexM I get that, what I mean is that maybe you can provide a sample of your data, in which there are rows which correspond to each other, so we can try to see what the problem is.

Comment: @DS_UNI thanks for noticing this however... I see now on this small example that R simply replaces values in columns that have different values so that I have finally 3, not 6 columns... That's absolutely not the way I thought it is working. Maybe I should reformulate my question then: How can I get ALL values from both tables in one with NAs in lines where there is no correspondence?.. Or shall I start a new discussion on that?.. Sorry for me not noticing this important issue before...

Comment: If you want rows from both tables either use the argument ``all = TRUE`` in merge (instead of ``all.x = TRUE``), or the ``dplyr`` function ``full_join()``

Comment: @DS_UNI I've found it! It's "all = TRUE" that should be added to merge in order to keep data from both tables even when they don't correspond each other! It also solves my initial problem!

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding observations? I would also recommend using library(dplyr).

```
left_join(x, y, by = c("a" = "b"), copy = FALSE, suffix = c(".x", ".y"), ...)
```

make sure `FLatSchool` is on the 'left' to keep those values.
in the by statement you can have multiple variables.

**suffix**  =
If there are non-joined duplicate variables in x and y, these suffixes will be added to the output to disambiguate them. Should be a character vector of length 2.

Check this site out:
https://rpubs.com/williamsurles/293454

Comment: Thank you! I know dplyr, but I wanted to solve the problem by using merge function. Actually I've found out what the problem was: I had to put "all = TRUE" to the formula when merging...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for responding! The problem is solved, I just had to put "all = TRUE" to the merge formula:

```
all_data = merge (data_id, data_id_1, by=c("ID_w2", "ID_w3", "ID_w4", "ID_w5",
                                        "ID_MC_w3", "ID_MC_w5",
                                        "School", "Class"),
              all.x = T , all = T)
```